# mysql IS NULL and IS NOT NULL not mutually exclusive

Tags: mysql, null

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE datefield IS NULL
```

Returns 20 records

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE datefield IS NOT NULL
```

Returns the same 20 records and a further 20 records where the date is entered

Aren't `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` mutually exclusive?

Field definition is:
`datefield date NOT NULL`

Comment: Uhmmmm... you have a NOT NULL column and when you SELECT for column IS NULL you get 20 rows?!? I can't really believe that.

Comment: probably if you share some data in the table that would be good to analyze, may be you have date data as well as data with null, how many total records you have in the table ?

Comment: Thank you - herein is my problem I think - if a field is date format and NOT NULL what is in the field when you create a record with no date data in the field - if that makes any sense.  i.e. the datefield is only populated on an update perhaps a year after the original insert.  What I want to know is how to select only the records that have a date in them - the ones that have been updated

Comment: Frazz - you're quite right - datefield contains 0000-00-00 - which doesn;t show in my report because the sql is DATE_FORMAT(b.datefield, '%D %b %y').  Sound of humble pie being eaten - thanks for your help

Comment: problem solved - thank you Frazz - thank you Abhik

Answer (score 0):

A `NOT NULL` column that doesn't have an explicit default value will use the implicit default value (for the type). For a `date` column, the default value is `0`.

From MySQL [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html):

> If the column cannot take NULL as the value, MySQL defines the column
>   with an explicit DEFAULT clause, using the implicit default value for
>   the column data type. Implicit defaults are defined as follows:
>
> - For date and time types other than TIMESTAMP, the default is the appropriate “zero” value for the type. For the first TIMESTAMP column
>     in a table, the default value is the current date and time. See
>     Section 11.3, “Date and Time Types”.